# Don’t you think the tour page should contain the essence of how to ask a good question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just pointed a new user to the tour page, because his answer had several formatting issues and the like. However, it just occurred to me that the tour page doesn’t actually have any references on writing a good answer.

Maybe a gist of this [legendary article](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) would work?

Comment: The more you add to it, the fewer will read it entirely. Maybe some links at the end for the bibliophile.

Comment: You can use `[help], [help/on-topic], [help/dont-ask], [ask] (how to ask), [answer] (how to answer)` to link to the help center topics on asking questions. I think there's a feature request to make `[help/mvce]` a link as well.

Comment: @BSMP relative links don’t work :p

Comment: `[help]` creates [help]. `[help/on-topic]` creates [help/on-topic]. `[help/dont-ask]` creates [help/dont-ask]. `[ask]` creates [ask]. `[answer]` creates [answer].

Comment: Which ones didn't work for you?

Comment: Question or answer?